# ConcurrentModificationException even when using synchronized

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two threads: first one is an render thread, the second thread is the main thread in which I handle UI actions.

I get the following error:

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:95)
at com.convekta.android.chessboard.ChessBoard.renderGamerPieces(ChessBoard.java:424)
at com.convekta.android.chessboard.ChessBoard.render(ChessBoard.java:162)
at com.convekta.android.chessboard.ChessDrawThread.run(ChessDrawThread.java:41)`

The usual reason of ConcurrentModification exception is changing of iterated list, but I only read it in `renderGamerPieces` function. The only place where `mGamerPieces` may change is `loadPosition` method, but both `loadPosition` and `renderGamerPieces` are called inside synchronized blocks

Maybe I didn't understand something.. So how this error may appear?

My code:

```
private final List<DrawablePiece> mGamerPieces = new ArrayList<DrawablePiece>();
private final Object mGamerPiecesLock = new Object();

public void loadPosition(byte[] pieces, byte[] places) {
        synchronized (mGamerPiecesLock) {
            mPicked = null;
            mGamerPieces.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
                byte p = GamerUtils.UncastleRook(pieces[i]);
                if (p != GamerPieces.EMPTY) {
                    byte pl = places[i];
                    if (pl <= GAME_BOARDSIZE)
                        mGamerPieces.add(new DrawablePiece(p,
                                GamerUtils.columnByCell(pl), GamerUtils.rowByCell(pl,
                                        true)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void renderGamerPieces(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, mCellSize, mCellSize);
    List<DrawablePiece> over = new ArrayList<DrawablePiece>();

    for (DrawablePiece d : mGamerPieces) {
        if (d.isFloating()) {
            over.add(d);
        } else {
            r.offsetTo(invert(d.getBoardCol()) * mCellSize,
                    invert(d.getBoardRow()) * mCellSize);
            r.offset(mBoardRegion.left, mBoardRegion.top);
            Bitmap pic = mPieceFactory.getBitmapPiece(d.getPiece(),
                    mCellSize);
            if (null != pic)
                canvas.drawBitmap(pic, null, r, null);
        }
    }
    ...
 }

public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        ...
        synchronized (mGamerPiecesLock) {
            renderGamerPieces(canvas);
        }
        ...
}
```

Thank you for comments! I will tidy up my code - add synchronization block in `renderGamerPieces`, and check can `loadPosition` be called from another synchronized block.

Comment: is `loadPosition` called from `renderGamerPieces`?

Comment: No, `loadPosition` is called from other classes, not from this class.

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that you are overlooking something. Here's my shot in the dark: `renderGamePieces` is public, but you don't synchronize within that method. You may be calling it from somewhere else, where you don't synchronize. Even if this is not the problem, you *should* synchronize from within that method because it is essential to its correctness.

Comment: As from stack trace it's called from render.

Comment: Is that bug stably reproducabe or happens sometimes?

Comment: It happens very rare, 0.1% of all launches and on user's device, not mine.

Comment: As workaround you can use CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: Please, make sure that are the only usages of mGamerPieces. How you use it seems to be correct from JMM point of view.

Comment: If you want to track it down, first you need to reproduce it - try use something like jstress. Run it on ARM, you surely won't reproduce it on x86. Do you have any info about devices on which this bug happens (especially processor)?

Comment: There are another usages but they are also included into synchronized blocks. Now I want to tidy up my code based on your comments. Thank you!

Comment: Device is FLY IQ230. Processor have ARMv7 architecture.

Comment: Do you modify **only** non-static fields in your synchronization blocks?

Comment: Yes, only non-static. All static fields are also final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made code refactoring by making synchronized blocks as small as can and problem became solved. Apparently there was a subsequent call from one synchronized block to another.